# SSMS 2017 crash

Tags: sql-server, crash, ssms

Are you guys can use maintenance schedule time or it crash Management Studio on click?

[image: MSSQL 2017 CRASH]

I tried reinstall MSSQL but didn't help. What else can try to solved it?

Comment: Have you installed the last upgrade package? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Did you try to Reinstall SSMS or SQL Server? They are completely different things.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin

Yes, before few days download installation and install.

Comment: @Larnu

Tried both but didn't help. Many say its know bug so going try downgrade to 17.5 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All say need to install 17.5 SSMS to solved maintenance plan crash, but they forget to write before install 17.5 need uninstall 17.6 SSMS before installing 17.5.

1) uninstall SSMS 17.6 
2) download SSMS 17.5 https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=867670 
3) install 17.5

UPDATE
new version fixed bug
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=875804

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have SSMS v 17.6, which has a known issue:

> There is a known issue where SSMS 17.6 becomes unstable and crashes
>   when using Maintenance Plans. If you use Maintenance Plans, do not
>   install SSMS 17.6. Downgrade to SSMS 17.5 if you already installed
>   17.6 and this issue is affecting you.

The information is from the link below:

[SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The other (better) solution is to stop using maintenance plans. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I am using the last version downloaded from Microsoft web. Going try downgrade. 

@AaronBertrand

Sorry cannot stop use it after 5 years of usage. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue. Install 17.5, that should fix it. Download 17.5 from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=867670

Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Still same problem with 17.5. Any more idea what to try?